# Visual Studio Compile Source

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I would like to compile the source:
https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall

I'm have downloaded the source launch visual studio and open heimdall/main.cpp 
However when trying F5 nothing happening.

Please help

Comment: You probably need to place the source file into a VS project.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a VS project to be able to compile it

Comment: it looks complicated, never done it before, is there a step by step instruction? thx I need only command line

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Readmes (e.g. [Win32](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/tree/master/Win32)):

> Appendix B - Installing Heimdall Suite from Source
>
> ```
> Heimdall and Heimdall Frontend both utilise CMake for managing the build
> process. CMake can generate files for various build systems including GNU
> Make and Visual Studio. However, official packages are compiled with GNU
> Make and MinGW-W64 GCC/G++.
>
> NOTE: Official builds use MinGW-W64 simply because on-going cross-platform
>       development is simpler when using just the one IDE (Jetbrain's CLion)
>       and similar toolchains.
>
> 1. Setup a MinGW-W64 build environment by utilising MSYS2:
>
>     http://msys2.github.io/
>
> 2. After installing MSYS2 a command prompt will launch, enter:
>
>     Pacman -Syu
>     Pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64 mingw-w64-x86_64-clang mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-libusb mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-static make
>
> 3. Add the MinGW-W64 binaries to your PATH environment variable:
>
>     export PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH"
>
> 4. Build Heimdall & Heimdall Frontend
>
>     mkdir build
>     cd build
>     cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DQt5Widgets_DIR=/c/msys64/mingw64/qt5-static/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets ..
>     make
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [v1.4.0](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/tree/v1.4.0) tag, open msvc2012.sln and build that code instead.
You will need [Qt Developer Framework (4.7 or later, but prior to 5.0)](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) to build it